# Excel | Disable button at start

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I am working on an excel file that will work as a calendar with specifications.
I want to have a button at each day. Since I want this to be reusable for other years, I will have buttons on columns with no days (for example, if January starts on a tewsday, Monday will have a button, but nothing on the day, since it is from December).

[image]

I know it is possible to set a button enable = False, but I don't know where to put that code. I don't want it to be disabled when another button is clicked but at the opening of the file.
I am new to vba, I'm sorry if this is something really simple.

Comment: 1. Do you have the buttons at all times? Wouldn't you rather for this to be dynamic? 2. Is there any difference on the code that is called when "Enviar" is clicked or is just the date that takes into account?

Comment: @Sgdva How can I do it dynamically? The only difference is the day.

Comment: There are two things that come to my mind. 1. Have a cell where they pick the date (it may be even today's by default by using =Now()) and just one button next to it that will be based on this cell entry.  2. If you really need one button per day, I would change the button to be an image shape instead, and then assign the same macro for all these images appended, the macro would take the date based on the cell the image is. I'd strongly recomending going the first path though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach needs those cells with days from previous month to be empty or "", if theres any value inside it wont work (instead you change the logic to treat cells values like numbers instead of strings).

I noticed that days in your calendar are in string format or so (i.e: "01") that's why I use Len() to evaluate length of string.

This code will set buttons visibility based on TopLeftCell value. Visible = True to days with some value, and Visible = False to empty values.

There is a way to make a button "Enable" but that property is for buttons inside an UserForm.

Tell me if it works for your case, since Sheet.CurrentRegion may cause some issues if your cells are way to much separate from each other, plus it could also hide some other buttons you have. If any of those scenarios do happen let me know, I'll continue helping you anyways!

```
Sub Set_Buttons_Visibility()

  Dim Sheet As Worksheet
  Dim Calendar_DataBodyRange As Range
  Dim Shape As Shape

    'Set Calendar range
    Set Sheet = ActiveSheet                         'Set Sheet
    Set Calendar_DataBodyRange = Sheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion      'Set current region
    Calendar_DataBodyRange.Select   '<- comment this after you tested everything[']

    'Hide buttons from previous month
    For Each Shape In Sheet.Shapes
        'If Shape.Visible Then Shape.Select
        
    'Get variables
        'Get Button day, as string
        strTemp = CStr(Shape.TopLeftCell)
        
        'Get range occupied by button
        Set rngTemp = Sheet.Range(Shape.TopLeftCell, Shape.BottomRightCell)
        'rngTemp.Select
        
    'Test conditions
        'Test rngTemp is part of Calendar_DataBodyRange
        bInRange = Not Intersect(Calendar_DataBodyRange, rngTemp) Is Nothing
        
        'Test TopLeftCell has some string
        bString = (Len(strTemp) > 0)
        
        'Test bInRange and bShow (True and True)
        bCondition = (bString = False) And bInRange
        
    'Perform action
        'Set shape visibility
        Shape.Visible = Not (bCondition)
        
        'Delete shape (only if you have another procedure to rebuild all buttons)
        ''''Shape.delete
    Next
    
End Sub
```

**Run code when workbooks opens**

To start this function when workbook opens, go to `VBA Project Explorer` > [`ThisWorkbook`](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-workbook/#Using-ThisWorkbook) then inside the module you can bind your code to [`Workbook_Open`](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/vba-workbook-events/) event. Later on (depending in where you've have stored your code) use the following [`Run`](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/application-run.htm) function.

**Important:**
According to your case you might need to store your code 1) inside the sheet you are working on, in other cases you store your code 2) in a single sheet usually called `PERSONAL.XLSB` that is always open when `Excel` itself Opens ([Know more about this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/03/04/excel-personal-macro-workbook/)) so your functions can be accesible for all sheets that you work on.

**Pros and Cons:**
On the first case is perfect for sharing your work with your boss or colleagues since your code is locally stored in the sheet (but is harder to update, and hard to back up) and the second case is optimal for your own use since all your functions are in the same workbook so you can call it like `"[Workbook.Name]![FunctionName],[FunctionParameters]"` (allows you to do better updating and an easier backup just by copy-pasting). In any case you can addapt to your necessities.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Run sintax needs Workbook [extension] and string [!]

    'Function is stored in current workbook (case 1)
    Run ThisWorkbook.Name & "!Set_Buttons_Visibility"
  
    'Function is stored in PERSONAL (case 2)
    Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Set_Buttons_Visibility"


End Sub
```

Comment: your code worked. I have other buttons that also got hidden because I also have a button for each week, but I can solve that by just writing something on the top cell (like the number of the week). But I have a question. To try the code, I called it on a button_click() sub. But I want this code to run when I open the book, or if I change the calendar year. Where should I call this sub? (I am new to VBA, sorry if this is basic).

Comment: Hey there! Glad it helped! I updated my answer, check it and tell me if it works for you

Comment: Hey there! I added some lines of code and more comments. Now code logic hides buttons under two conditions: button is in calendar range and string in cell is empty. It will not longer affect those buttons outside Calendar Range. Consider that under this logic you have to pay more attention to "what range is set at Calendar Range"; if you have to, try to addapt the section [Set Calendar range]  so it can match exactly the range you want this code to have effect. Any questions or doubts let me know!